# Hibernate throws NullPointerException in EntityVerifyVersionProcess

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

In a `WebApplication` with Hibernate, I'm using a standard interceptor to create and commit my transactions. However, I'm getting a `NullPointerException` when the transaction is committed.

The error hints to bad session-management, but I don't know why.
I can only find very little information about this particular error. Can anybody help?

---

**Stacktrace:**

```
2011-04-20 10:20:57,016 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-7] ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityVerifyVersionProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EntityVerifyVersionProcess.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:543)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.beforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:138)
    at com.innovigent.ptaserver.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:571)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.beforeTransactionCompletion(JDBCContext.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:138)
    at com.innovigent.ptaserver.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityVerifyVersionProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EntityVerifyVersionProcess.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:543)
    ... 21 more
```

**Interceptor class:**

```
public class HibernateSessionRequestFilter implements Filter {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.class);

    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    try{
    log.debug("Starting a database transaction");
    sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    log.debug("Comitting the database transaction");
    sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Throwable ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

            try {
                if (sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                    log.debug("Trying to rollback database transaction after exception");
                    sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                }
            } catch (Throwable rbEx) {
                log.error("Could not rollback transaction after exception!", rbEx);
            }

            // Let others handle it... maybe another interceptor for exceptions?
            throw new ServletException(ex);
    }

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    log.debug("Initializing HibernateSessionRequestFilter");
    sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/db</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">db</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
   <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

... some reference to mapping xml files ...

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error was caused because I had set the LockMode of my Criteria-query to LockMode.OPTIMISTIC. Removing this setting solved the problem..

Answer (score 2):

Have you added @Version and the field of type long to the entity class in order to support Optimistic Locking ?

```
 @Version
 public long version;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you

> To enable the thread-bound strategy in
>   your Hibernate configuration: set
>   hibernate.transaction.factory_class to
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
>   set
>   hibernate.current_session_context_class
>   to thread

(from [the docs](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Sessionsandtransactions#Transaction_demarcation_with_plain_JDBC) )

Also when I understand the docs right, the session is put in the thread the filter and thus all invoked methods are on. Are you sure you are not fiddling with the Hibernate session in it (like getting a session later and committing it)?

Comment: My hibernate.cfg.xml contains the correct parameters: 
  " <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property> "

I always use the getCurrentSession()-function in my DAO-objects, and I only run some queries on that session, nothing else..